# NACL on chromium

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, google-nativeclient

I do not know if this falls under the ramifications of what this website handles, but I was wondering if there is a way to install nacl onto chromium since it was removed from ubuntu's chromium repository

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the Ubuntu maintainers compiled Chromium. If they disabled NaCl at build time with the DISABLE_NACL gn flag (which I'm guessing is likely) then there's no way to add it back without recompiling Chromium. Otherwise it's possible they simply left out the NaCl IRT nexe and/or NaCl trusted runtime file (I can't remember those file names off the top of my head, but I can find out).